# Visual Studio Code support for Substrate?

Tags: pallet

I use both Visual Studio Enterprise and Visual Studio Code as IDEs. I'm trying to learn how to build substrate pallets. I found this plugin, but it's no longer supported. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paritytech.vscode-substrate&ssr=false#overview Does anyone know of a good VSC extension for substrate development? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In, general I would say do check out the Tools section for [Awesome Substrate](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate#tools). More specifically on VSCode, I think what will be helpful on your IDE setup would be similar to what is helpful on a Rust programming setup. I would recommend [watching something like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_iZEK6Rww4) to get a sense of what plugins might come in handy.

Comment: Thanks! Should I just follow the instructions in the video to setup my Rust environment and then do something like this to install Substrate. git clone https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template

Comment: Yes that's a good starting point!

Comment: I realize the original question was about Substrate but I'm looking to build Substrate Pallets. Here is a video showing how to use Swanky. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyKk5-ynQjc Perhaps this would be a better development environment for me.

Comment: What about using Ink in Visual Studio Code? Looks like this guy highly recommends it. https://medium.com/block-journal/introducing-substrate-smart-contracts-with-ink-d486289e2b59